# Angular routing - how to design routing for 3 optional parameters?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I'm in a very weird situation currently. I have a structure that has three levels. Well, basically, I have a `parent -> child -> subchild` directory with respect to the navigation. For example:

- `Vehicles -> Cars -> Fast cars`
- `Vehicles -> Cars -> Slow cars`
- `Vehicles -> Airplanes -> Commercial Airplanes`

Now, the data I get are represented in a way that parent has no items. If I'd make a request with only `Vehicles`, I'd get nothing, where as both `Cars` and `Fast cars` have contents. But that's just how the data is structured, it's beyond my control.

So, as evident, my url can at any time be either `my-app.com/vehicles/cars` or `my-app.com/vehicles/cars/slow-cars`. Both these paths need to display a list of items. Moreover, user can just as well type `my-app.com/vehicles`. It is important that the url is in this manner, and not some `,child=cars`.

To create a routing (and the whole structure) for this specification is a bit much. Here's how I approached the thing.

Since I haven't been able to find any reference as to how to create optional parameters, I had to duplicate routes, like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ArticlesHomeComponent
}, {
  path: ':first',
  component: ArticlesHomeComponent
}, {
  path: ':first/:second',
  component: ArticlesHomeComponent
}, {
  path: ':first/:second/:third',
  component: ArticlesHomeComponent
}];
```

Now, I really hate this. It's duplicating and whatnot, but given the current circumstances, I have no idea how to do this any differently.

When the `ArticlesHomeComponent` is loaded, I check to see how many parameters are available. If `first` is not, I redirect to the first item in the navigation. If the `second` is also not available, I get the first child of parent and redirect. Only then can I display some content.

It seems hack-y and wrong to have this approach. What do you guys think?

Comment: Use queryParams instead of optional paramaters

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

Comment: yeah I wish I could do that, the url must be in this manner `something/something-else` and not `something?id=something-else`

Comment: Instead of your proposed solution you could use child routes. See https://angular.io/guide/router#a-crisis-center-with-child-routes

Comment: would it make sense to use child routes for path that resolves to the some component? Wouldn't that create a loop or something?